# Removing an item for a list without reducing the total number

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here we go again. So what I am trying to do is, let's say I have a list like this:

```
List = ['one','two','three']
```

And they are all assigned to numbers 0,1,2 for example:

```
'one': 0, 'two': 1, 'three': 2
```

What I want to do now is I want to remove an item from my list... let's say two

```
List.remove('two')
```

But if I do this, 'three' goes into the place of two and the total amount decreases by one. Is there a way I can remove two, but still keep the total amount of objects in a list, with the ones being removed just being replaced with 'None' or something similar?

Comment: You can replace the element to be removed with some object.

Comment: If they're all "assigned to numbers", are you sure you shouldn't be using a dict instead of a list?

Comment: While the question is similar to mine, I didn't really find the answer as helpful as what James answered below.

Comment: I thought so. Maybe you should accept James answer then.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can replace it with `None` or with an empty string `''` using:

```
List[List.index('two')] = None
# List = ['one', None, 'three']
```

or

```
List[List.index('two')] = ''
# List = ['one', '', 'three']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the dictionary and replace the value that you want to remove:

```
s = {'one': 0, 'two': 1, 'three': 2}
target = "two"
new_s = {a if a != target else None:b for a, b in s.items()}
```

Output:

```
{'one': 0, 'three': 2, None: 1}
```

This way, the count value for "two" is retained, but the key substituted with `None`

Comment: `What I want to do now is I want to remove an item from my list` I think OP wants to remove the item from a list and leave the dictionary (which I assume is just a look up for where the key should be if it exist) alone.